# Angular JS Angular input dropdown control not getting rendered properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, laravel

I am using your Angular JS Input Dropdown control, and I've followed the code example you put on your demo page to implement the control on a page in my PHP Laravel based website. I have found a problem with the implementation, though, and I was unable to identify what triggered it or how to fix it, so I was hoping that one of you may be of some assistance.

The issue consists of the control **not getting rendered** into the page **until** I **refresh the page**, then it shows up and works perfectly fine, right **until** I **leave the page** and **get back to i**t; forcing me to refresh the page every time I re-enter it to be able to use the control.

To elaborate further, the control **does not get rendered**, but the page **acknowledges** that there is supposed to be a control on the page, which is why it displays a **white blank space** at the position where the control is supposed to be. So, I am pretty sure that it's a rendering issue.

The website is using Voyager which has a navigation sidebar, and if the page is entered via the sidebar button, the issue occurs, while if it was entered directly through the url bar or refreshed, then it works fine.

Has this ever happened to anyone before, and if so, how should I go on about fixing it? If not, then what do you propose might be the issue?

Thanks for taking your time to read this issue, and have a wonderful day.

Link to Angular control repository: https://github.com/hannaholl/angular-input-dropdown

---

EDIT: This issue was self-fixed.
Solution: Manually bootstrap Angular JS.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was self-fixed.
Solution: Manually bootstrap Angular JS.